# Ionic Angular : Create generic http error handler

Tags: angular, error-handling, ionic2

I'm new to angular2 and I do my http requests like this :

```
this.http.get(...).map(res=>res.json()).subscribe(data=>{
   //..do something
},err=>{

   if(err.status == 400){
      this.presentToast('Validation error');
   }else if(err.status == 403){
      this.presentToast('Authorization error'):
   }else if(err.status == 500){
      this.presentToast('Something wrong with server');
   }else ...
});
```

I wanted a custom message for each of the common status codes that users can understand, but the problem is I write these **if and else blocks** to each and every http request I do, and in every ts file I have, so basically I import ToastController in every ts file and write the **presentToast** function.

Is there anyway to make a generic error handler that is decorated in a way that it presents the custom rules/messages as a toast and make it DRY?

Comment: simply create some Global service and call each http request from there, by doing so you will be able to set global error handler messages as well as you can save no line of code

Comment: Ionic 2 has the Alerts check http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#alert

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by creating a common Observable like this:

your `common.ts` will have this method: (Say, this component is `CommonProvider` as in written in `CommonProvider` class).

```
httpGetCall(url){
    return Observable.create(observer => {
        this.http.get(url)
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(data => {
            console.log("Your data : " , data);
            observer.next(data);
        },(err) => {
            console.log("Your error : ", err);
            observer.error(err);
            if(err.status == 400){
                this.presentToast('Validation error');
            }else if(err.status == 403){
                 this.presentToast('Authorization error'):
            }else if(err.status == 500){
                 this.presentToast('Something wrong with server');
            }else ...
        });
    });
}
```

From your calling method, you can do this:

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: "<your-html-path/code>",
    providers: [CommonProvider]
})
export class YourPage{
    constructor(private common: CommonProvider){
        this.common.httpGetCall(<url>)
        .subscribe(data => {
            //..do something
        },(err) => {
            //.. Any other operation or nothing to do as toast action is already done.
        })
    }
}
```

Though, this is just in case you need a common handler.